# Want to upload video on cloudkit dashboard and display that video in an ios app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit

I want to upload a video on cloudkit dashboard and display that video in an iOS app... searched about my query and came to know that using asset type we can do it.. but not getting exactly how to achieve it programmatically in Objective-c.

How can I do it programmatically in Objective-c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solution for my problem.here is the code which I used to display video for those who may got such problem.

```
                CKAsset * asset=[videoArray objectAtIndex:0];  
                NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:asset.fileURL];
                if ( urlData )
                 {
                 //save video 
                    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                    NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.mp4"];
                   [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
                   NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
                 //Play video
                   AVPlayer * avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];
                   AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
                   avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
                  layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
                  [self.view.layer addSublayer: layer];
                  [avPlayer play];
                 }
```